# Loop through an array to query another formula which will produce a new array of results

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-4

My first query returns the correct `ID` values:

```
$coordinates = Coordinate::select('id')
    ->whereBetween('lat', array($minlat, $maxlat))
    ->whereBetween('lng', array($minlng, $maxlng))
    ->get();
```

Using `DD` to output the results returns (shortened for example):
`["original":protected]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> string(4) "1495" }`

Now, there will be over 100 of these IDs, what I want to now do is, look through another table - `Locations`, and match any rows that have this ID within their `coordinate_id` column, and return `all columns`.

Initially, I thought along the lines of this:

```
foreach($coordinates as $coordinate)
    {
        echo(Location::where('id', '=', $coordinate));
    }
```

But, that returns a loop!

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
$coordinates = Coordinate::select('id')
    ->whereBetween('lat', array($minlat, $maxlat))
    ->whereBetween('lng', array($minlng, $maxlng))
    ->get();
```

use:

```
$coordinates = Coordinate::whereBetween('lat', array($minlat, $maxlat))
    ->whereBetween('lng', array($minlng, $maxlng))
    ->lists('id'); // array of ids

// then
$locations = Location::whereIn('coordinate_id', $coordinates)->get();
```

It will return collection of Location models, that you are looking for.

You could also use `whereHas` if you have `coordinate` relation setup:

```
$locations = Location::whereHas('coordinate', function ($q) use ($minlat, $maxlat, $minlng, $maxlng) {
   $q->whereBetween('lat', array($minlat, $maxlat))
     ->whereBetween('lng', array($minlng, $maxlng));
})->get();
```

Comment: Jarek, excellent and thoroughly explained answers, as always. Thank you. I do have a relationship between the two models set up. However, using the last formula, I get `syntax error, unexpected '}'`, on the `})->get();` line.

Comment: Fixed, it was just `;` missing in the closure.

Comment: Thank you Jarek, as always, you help is greatly appreciated.